Container does not see installed packages
While trying to fine-tune mistral-7b inside a container, I am getting this error:
ImportError: Using `bitsandbytes` 8-bit quantization requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate` and the latest version of bitsandbytes: `pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes`

Both packages are installed per instructions. For contet, this is my dockerfile:
# Use NVIDIA CUDA 12.0.0 development image based on Ubuntu 22.04 as the base image
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.4.0-devel-ubuntu22.04

# Set non-interactive mode to avoid prompts during package installation
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update the package list and install python3-pip
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git curl wget python3 python3-pip python3-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements.txt file to the container
COPY *.sh /app/
COPY *.py /app/
COPY *.txt /app/

RUN pip3 install -q -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate.git
RUN pip3 install -q -U bitsandbytes
RUN pip3 install -q -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
RUN pip3 install -q -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/peft.git
RUN pip3 install -q trl xformers wandb datasets einops sentencepiece

# Command to run your application
# CMD ["python3", "finetune.py"]

Where am I going wrong?

It seems a pretty poor choice to install prerequisite packages after the packages that require them

@talonmies How so?

Could you perhaps imagine a scenario where an installation script did a test where it tried to import a prerequisite  and then decided to do something different if that prerequisite wasn't found? And what would be the effect of installing the prerequisite before or after in such a scenario?

I understand what you mean but where in the Dockerfile am I doing that? I am not running anything before the pip installs that require the pip installs.

In the error message it says bitsandbytes requires accelerate. You install accelerate after bitsandbytes.

Check the update. I altered the pip install order but there is no difference. It gives the same error.
